# Find the Path for Excel-addin in Powershell

Tags: powershell, excel-addins

I need to create a Powershell script that can search for a custom installed Excel-Addin that we created. I then need to get the path of where the Addin exists and then copy a supporting file to that path.

The issue is I do not know the path of where the Addin is installed, it could vary from machine to machine so I need to be able to get the Addin object by name, then retrieve the path of the Addin and then copy a supporting file to that path.

All the examples I have found all use the path+name :

```
try {
       $Excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
} catch {
          Write-Error 'Microsoft Excel does not appear to be installed.'
}

try {
      $ExcelAddins = $Excel.Addins
      $AddinInstalled = $ExcelAddins | ? { $_.Name -eq "MyAddinName" } // this doesnt work, needs path

      if (!$AddinInstalled ) {        
        Write-Host ('Add-in "' + $Addin.BaseName + '" Not installed!')
      } else {
         // now get the path and copy supporting file to the path
         ...
         ...
         Write-Host ('Add-in "' + $Addin.BaseName + '" supporting file copied successfully!')
      }
  } finally {
              $Excel.Quit()
  }
```

The code above does not work because I don't supply the path. Is there a way to get the Addin by name or loop through the Addin and check name until I find the one I need and then get the path so I can copy a supporting file to that path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$Excel.Addins` returns objects with more properties than just the Name, but that Name property is the addins Filename and includes the extension, like `.XLL` or `.XLAM`.

Another property you could probe is the `.Title`.

Try

```
try {
    $Excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application

    $Excel.Visible = $false
    # you may also try Where-Object { $_.Title -match 'MyAddinName' }
    $myAddIn = $Excel.Addins | Where-Object { $_.Name -match 'MyAddinName' }

    if ($myAddIn) {
        Write-Host "AddIn '$($myAddIn.Name)' found in '$($myAddIn.Path)'"
        # copy the supporting file to the Addin's path
        Copy-Item -Path 'X:\YourSupportingFile' -Destination $myAddIn.Path
    }
    else {
        Write-Warning "Addin 'MyAddinName' not found"
    }
}
catch {
    Write-Warning "Error:`r`n$($_.Exception.Message)"
}
finally {
    if ($Excel) {
        # close and cleanup COM object
        $Excel.Quit()
        $null = [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($Excel)
        [System.GC]::Collect()
        [System.GC]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()
    }
}
```

<sup>This assumes there is only one addin found with that name..

Instead of the regex `-match` operator you could also use `-like '*MyAddinName*'` which uses wildcars</sup>

Comment: Perfect! Exactly what I was looking for!